# JPA - @MapKey and @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following DB structure:

[image: Main table FESTIVAL]

[image: Table with translation]

Where FESTIVAL_ID and LANG is composite PK and FESTIVAL_ID is FK for FESTIVAL.

In my Java code I  have the following entities:

```
@Embeddable
public class FestivalTranslationId {

    @Column(name = "FESTIVAL_ID")
    Long festivalId;

    @Column(name = "LANG")
    String lang;

    ...
}

public class FestivalTranslation {

    @EmbeddedId
    FestivalTranslationId id = new FestivalTranslationId();

    @MapsId(value = "festivalId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FESTIVAL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    Festival festival;

    @Column(name = "LANG")
    String lang;

    ...
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "FESTIVAL")
public class Festival {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "festival")
    @MapKey(name="lang")
    Map<String, FestivalTranslation> translations;

    ...
}
```

But when I try get festival entity I have the exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'translatio0_.ID' in 'field list'
```

In hibernate logs I see crazy sql query:

```
SELECT translatio0_.FESTIVAL_ID AS FESTIVAL1_14_0_,
       translatio0_.FESTIVAL_ID AS FESTIVAL1_15_0_,
       translatio0_.LANG AS LANG2_15_0_,
       translatio0_.ID AS ID3_15_0_,
       translatio0_.FESTIVAL_ID AS FESTIVAL1_15_1_,
       translatio0_.LANG AS LANG2_15_1_,
       translatio0_.ID AS ID3_15_1_
  FROM FESTIVAL_TRANSLATION translatio0_
 WHERE translatio0_.FESTIVAL_ID = ?
```

My question, is possible to use Map for entities with @EmbeddedId where key is part of composite PK?

Comment: So, the problem was in my java code and inattention. I had a parent class for  `FestivalTranslation` with `ID` field =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example approach may look as follows:

```java
@Embeddable
public class FestivalId implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "FESTIVAL_ID")
    private int id;
    ...
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class FestivalTranslationId implements Serializable {
    @Embedded
    private FestivalId festivalId;

    @Column(name = "LANG")
    private String lang;
    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "FESTIVAL")
public class Festival {
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "ID"))
    private FestivalId festivalId;

    @MapsId(value = "festivalId")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "festival")
    @MapKey(name = "festivalTranslationId")
    private Map<String, FestivalTranslation> translations;
    ...
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "FESTIVAL_TRANSLATION")
public class FestivalTranslation {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FestivalTranslationId festivalTranslationId;

    @ManyToOne
    private Festival festival;
    ...
}
```

The above entities produce the following tables:

```
FESTIVAL            FESTIVAL_TRANSLATION
--------            --------------------
ID    PK            FESTIVAL_ID    FK PK
                    LANG              PK
```

Tested with Hibernate 4.3.8.Final

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `lang` property from `Festival` entity you can't do it directly, because there is no `lang` mapping in `Festival`. You must do it like this: `@MapKey(name="id.lang")` because it is accessed through `FestivalTranslationId`.

There is a very similar problem described [here](http://hwellmann.blogspot.com/2010/07/jpa-20-mapping-map.html). However it looks like there may be some problems with the fact that `lang` mapping is present both in a key and in value of the map (it depends on actual JPA provider you're using - there are problems with it in Hibernate).